# Unable to add new css properties in Chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a strange issue with the Chrome dev tools. For some reason I can no longer add new CSS properties in the elements view. When I click to add a new property the edit field shows up but nothing happens when I type a letter.

The only key that does anything is the H-key which toggles the visibility of the selected element. Editing an existing property name works, as does editing the value of any property. I can even change the actual CSS-selector.

I've already downloaded a new copy of Chrome and trashed everything in ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome as well as all Google preferences in ~/Library/Preferences.

Anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Sounds like you've got a keyboard button stuck like Ctrl or other modifier.

Comment: Nothing indicated in the keyboard viewer, nor is there any problem in any other application. Every other way of entering text in the style panel works such as pasting text, both in existing property names and values, just not new properties.

The "h"-shortcut to hide properties has no modifier.

Comment: How did you end up solving this?